# Detect threads created by script

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

When I stop a script can i somehow identify if a thread belongs (Is created in script) to IronPython and kill it?

The user can for example create a infinite `Timer` and I need to kill those threads

Full code here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core/ScriptEngine/Python/PythonScriptEngine.cs

Comment: Not sure if you can sry but a work around(not perfect) but when a thread is created store the thread id then when your script stops kill all the treads by using the stored ids

Comment: I have no power over the script being executed, its a end user application powered by Python for flexibility. But I can offcourse store all threads in app domain before starting python and then kill those that were created during script execution. Seems a bit dangerous :D

Comment: @Anders, using an app-domain for the python engine is your only chance to ensure that resources allocated by a script (not only threads) are being removed. Of course there are other things you can attempt in a specific scenario but as you hinted they are most likely very error prone.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right, which leads to the need for memory pipes to communicate with the appdomain etc..